# MVC 5 populate a model with Json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult WeatherWidget()
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        json = client.DownloadString("http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxxx/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Australia/sydney.json");
    }

    WeatherWidget weatherWidget = new WeatherWidget()
    {
        //What do I put in here?
    };

    return View(weatherWidget);
}
```

And the following model:

```
public class WeatherWidget
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the json:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "geolookup": 1
  ,
  "conditions": 1
  ,
  "forecast": 1
  }
    }
    ,"location": {
        "type":"INTLCITY",
        "country":"AU",
        "country_iso3166":"AU",
        "country_name":"Australia",
        "state":"VC",
        "city":"Falls Creek",
        "tz_short":"AEST",
        "tz_long":"Australia/Melbourne",
        "lat":"-36.86999893",
        "lon":"147.27000427",
        "zip":"00000",
```

How do I populate the model to display in my view?

e.g.. **@Model.city** or **@Html.Raw(Model.city)**

I have no problem displaying the data via Javascript in my view and I can do this with XML and Html using the HtmlAgilityPack, I just can't work out how to do it with Json.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json and create a series of POCO objects with the appropriate properties.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Newtonsoft.Json via NuGet, add the following using statements

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

and then use the following code to extract the data out of your JSON response.

```
  JObject parsedJson = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
  JObject location = (JObject)parsedJson["location"];
  WeatherWidget weatherWidget = new WeatherWidget();
  weatherWidget.city = location["city"];
  weatherWidget.lat = location["lat"];
  weatherWidget.lon = location["lon"];
```